# binding a user keypress - advanced registration

Tags: javascript

b0 is my binding method which calls the code to run after an enter press.  o5 simply gets the elements onkeypress and sets the callback to b0.  This does not work.  This worked when I had the b0 attached to the onkeypress event wih inline registration.  How is b0 suppose to know what 'event' is?  With inline registration it "knows", with advanced registration event is just another variable I'm guesssing?

```
function b0(event)
  {if (event.keyCode==13)
    {i4();
    return false;}}


function o5('f4b_',b0);

o5(a,b){document.getElementById(a).onkeypress=b;}
```

Comment: why your function names are like this OO ?? Who knows this advanced registration!!

Comment: @Chris - per James' comment about missing the function keyword... you added the `function` keyword to the *call* of `o5` rather than to the _declaration_ of `o5` -- that is, you added it to the wrong line.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're passing a string to `o5`, and assigning that string to the `onkeypress` property of the element, when really you want to be passing a reference to the function:

```
o5('f4b_', b0); //No quotes!
```

That should fix it. Also, I'm assuming it's just a typo when writing the question, but you're missing the `function` keyword before the definition of `o5`.

See it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9r47C/4/).

Comment: thanks...all works now..my assumption is that there is a "function prototype for b0 which tells it that event is an "event"...where is the documentation for this?  I'll check mdn but I have not seen it there.

Comment: Yes, an `event` object is passed automatically to an event handler. I'm not sure where this behaviour is defined, but the MDN page is worth a read: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Event